# gdal translate always generate empty .tif file

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

I have a .tif file, which looks like the image below.
[image]

I am trying to crop it into small patches. In colab python, I use the following code:

```
upper_left_x = -1476622.552
upper_left_y = 2423913.9703

lower_right_x = -1461423.802
lower_right_y = 2410231.7253

window = (upper_left_x,upper_left_y,lower_right_x,lower_right_y)
gdal.Translate('/content/proj_out.tif', '/content/patch.tif',  projWin = window)
```

These coordinates can be found in QGIS, with upper left corner smallest x and largest y. Then I read this proj_out.tif file, it is 2 dimension matrix, filling with -3.4028235e+38.

```
img_ds=gdal.Open('/content/pro_out.tif')
band1 = img_ds.GetRasterBand(1) # Red channel
b1 = band1.ReadAsArray()
print(b1)
```

Following is my geometry transform information:[image]

By gdal.GetProjection, I get these infomation:

PROJCS["NAD83 / Conus Albers",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5070"]]

Following is gdal info:
[image]

I really have no idea how to deal with it. My future purpose is to crop large .tif file into small ones with fixed size.

Comment: Are you sure the spatial reference of the image matches your coordinates for the projwin?

Comment: Are you reading it in the same script you wrote it in?

Comment: should the window not be lower_left, upper_right?

Comment: @IanTurton No. From the doc  `projWin -- subwindow in projected coordinates to extract: [ulx, uly, lrx, lry]`

Comment: Are you sure that the array gets defined right with `window = (upper_left_x,upper_left_y,lower_right_x,lower_right_y)`? You can find example about using projWin from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_translate_lib.py. I would also check with gdalinfo the native CRS and extent of the patch.tif to be sure that the projWin is within the image area.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I think so. I can find them in QGIS.

Comment: @user2856 Yes, I use google colab. they must be in the same script. I also update my question. Would you like to give me some advises if any?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, These coordinates can be found in QGIS. I also update my question. Would you like to give me some advises if any?

Comment: Have you tried to use square brackets `[ ]` instead of `( )` in your code? Have you tried to do crop the image with gdal_translate by using the same parameters?

Comment: Please run gdalinfo for the source image and show us the Upper Left and Lower Right corner coordinates.

Comment: @user30184 gdal. info updated